# Dovecot configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I was setting up a mail server on Amazon EC2 using postfix and dovcot and I seem to be stack on starting up dovecot service. Here is the message i got when I run

```
Service dovecot status 
dovecot stop/waiting
```

and with

```
dovecot -F
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: first_valid_uid can't be larger than last_valid_uid
```

does anyone have an idea, it would be most appreciated

Comment: Try opening your `dovecot.conf` or possibly one of the .conf files under the dovecot directory. In there there will be lines talking about UIDs, most likely for the virtual user associated with your virtual mailboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch `doveconf -a | grep _valid_`

You have to set that variables to something like that:

```
first_valid_uid         = 26
last_valid_uid          = 0
first_valid_gid         = 6
last_valid_gid          = 0
```

Comment: It turns out that the values of the variables where off so the moment i edited /etc/dovecote/conf.d/10-mail.conf to the right values it is working now. Thanks @Kondybas